# Simple post of info from one c# asp.net page to the next issue

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am not using MVC but forms authentication.  I am having trouble getting variable to store when the submit button is pressed.  I have spend 2 days researching how to do this.  At this point I am just trying to get the username to post on the next page. I truly thought I understood the way viewstate worked after doing this for a year.

Code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (IsPostBack) {
            string username = Page.Session["username"].ToString();
            Response.Write(username);
        }

    }

    protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Page.Session["username"] = txtUsername.Text;
    }
```

Comment: Does btnSubmit trigger a postback?

Comment: Well I have assumed yes.  How can I tell? When I remove the if(isPostback) code it just refreshes the page.  When I add it back now it is giving me the error Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: use break points and see where it is not working

Comment: try removing your if condition and **if (Session["username"] != null)** -> Write the session

Comment: It isn't working because the postback is happening BEFORE the value can be stored in the Session. See my answer for how to correct.

Answer (score 0):

So after some searching I found the issue. Your code is valid, however, the postback happens BEFORE your `Page.Session["username"] = txtUsername.Text;` which means that if you sat there and clicked the button again, you should see the results.

I was hesitant to post this until I figured out a way to fix it (because who cares why you're having a problem if there is no solution) and I figured it out. You need to change the "UseSubmitBehavior" to false for the button. So your Page_Load would look like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(IsPostBack) {
        string username = Page.Session["username"] as string; // will be null if empty
        Resopnse.Write(username);
    }
    btnSubmit.UseSubmitBehavior = false;
}
```

That should allow the value in txtUsername to be put into the Session variable before the postback and thus you will have access to it in the page load.